# Chrome DevTools cannot access variables from React Production Build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug a react application, but once it has been built, I can't access the variables through Chrome DevTools console.

For example, I have this component:

```
function TestComponent() {
  [pageState, setPageState] = useState({});
  debugger;
  return <div>Test</div>;
}
```

With `react start` command when Chrome stops at the debugger breakpoint, I can access the variable correctly.

But after I `react build` and `serve -s build` the variable won't exist.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: pageState is not defined

The application functions as normal though.

How do I fix this? Is this due to minification or transpiling?

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  Is it a runtime error or the result of your attempt to debug?  And yes, I would expect minification to  be the reason it's not accessible in your production build.  You can configure webpack to not minify for production or respond to a url param if you really need to debug in the live env.

Comment: When I attempt to debug. It functions as expected.

Comment: How does chrome have the original source code if it has been minified?